# How does the Kinect use random forests?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, application

I [read on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22511/2921) that apparently the Kinect uses the [random forests algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forests) for machine learning in some way.  Can anyone explain what it uses random forests for, and how their approach works?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would appear that the random forest is used [to predict movements of individual body parts](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/145347/BodyPartRecognition.pdf). In this sense, predict does not mean "predict where the body part will move to" but "best guess the 3D location of the body parts". [Here](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/105-artificial-intelligence/2176-kinects-ai-breakthrough-explained.html) is an overview of the method.