# Examples of machine learning in personal computers

Tags: machine-learning, references

Are there any examples of machine learning in our PC's? The only one that I know is Windows Speech Recognition application.

I do not mean any add-ons. I mean any basic applications that are available in most PC's.

**EDIT:** Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: Good question. Increasingly, the personal computer is a device running Android/iOS. I think it pays to consider how much of *that* revolution is caused by ML.

Comment: Because this merely asks for a list of things it doesn't really fit within the SE framework.  *What actual problem are you trying to solve?*

Comment: I want to start my Machine learning class by showing how PCs use some ML techniques. Any reference where to start would be helpful.

Comment: Somehow related, but was accepted as a "legit" although cw-question: [What can one tell a school kid about statistics and machine learning?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22504/what-can-one-tell-a-school-kid-about-statistics-and-machine-learning)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the implementation (or your definition of ML), spell checkers and grammar checkers would be a common example.

Answer (score 2):

Newer laptops allow one to login either through a fingerprint reader or via facial recognition.  I don't see the use of facial recognition that often though, but fingerprint readers built into laptops are becoming more common in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers might be using. Google chrome uses "bloom filter" inbuilt, though this a probabilistic approach, may not be considered as machine learning in pure sense.

Comment: I wonder if the machine learning that goes into Google Search and other Google products to show us adverts while we read our mail would be counted by the OP?